# A funciton that finds the maximum between two values?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, special-functions

Is there an $f$ that takes two values $a$ and $b$ and if $b>a$, it returns $f(a,b) = b-a$ otherwise $f(a,b) = 0$?

Is the $f$ linear?

P.S: I think one can find the maximum between $a$ and $b$ and then subtract $a$ from the maximum to get the desired $f$ described above.

Comment: By linear, you mean $F(x,y)=mx+ny$ for some constants $m,n$?  Pretty clear that no $m,n$ work.    Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Linear function...on **what** set? Does that thing look "linear"?

Comment: The question could be more simply phrased by asking whether that function is linear. $\qquad$

Comment: @lulu A function that could be implemented linearly, like in a linear optimization problem.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I modified the question.

Comment: @Mehdi: The title and the body of your question do not match. Your $f$ does not return what you say: for instance, $f(1,0) = 0$ - it clearly does not return the maximum.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks. the link you sent is very similar to my question and solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is "almost" linear
$$
\max\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}
$$

Comment: based on your comment I think $f$ could be $f(a,b) = \frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2} -a$. But why "almost" linear?

Comment: Why you need the $-a$? in the title you asked for the maximum. A linear function is one of the form $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=a_1 x_1+\ldots+a_nx_n$, not including absolute values.

Comment: You are right. What I really need is in the body of the question but actually did not know how to call an $f$ with such property. So I thought I can get the max and then use $-a$! How should such an $f$ be called?